# Verification of simple probability excercise

Tags: probability, solution-verification

**Task:** We have a 10 floor building, 7 people stand at the botton, waiting for the elevator. What is the chance that all people will exit on different floors?

**Proposed Solution:** I assume the cardinality of favorable outcomes is $$ \binom{10}{7}, $$ for it is given by the amount of ways you can choose 7 floors out of 10, without repetition.

Then the cardinality of total outcomes is $$ \binom{10+7-1}{7}=\binom{16}{7}, $$ as it is given by the amount of ways you can choose 7 floors out of 10 with possible repetition.

In this case, the probability is given by $$ P=\frac{\binom{10}{7}}{\binom{16}{7}}\approx0,0104895... $$

**The problem:** I believe my solution is correct, however the end result is *ugly*, which would not be a problem, but pretty much all excercises I have found in the batch this came from had "pretty" solutions, therefore, I am worried that this might be incorrect.
I would be terribly appreciative if someone could verify this solution.

Comment: The reason this is incorrect is that the ${16 \choose 7}$ outcomes do not have the same probability.  They would if the people behaved like bosons (indistinguishable elementary particles) but they don't.  For example, all people getting out on a certain floor does not have the same probability as half of them getting out on each of 2 particular floors which has many combinations, not just 1 combination.

Comment: @BruceZ Thank your for your response. I find rather annoying to distingush these two but I get what you're saying... I just find it rather unbelievable that if we replaced the 7 distinct people with 7 identical androids then this result would change. After all, we care more about the floors chosen than the identity of people choosingthem, nope?

Comment: If the androids were merely identical, it wouldn't matter since they would still be distinct entities that we could label as 1,2,..7.  There would still be 7 ways to distribute them on 2 floors as (6,1) and only 1 as (7,0).  Indistinguishable would mean there is only 1 way to do (6,1) because there is no way to even label them.  That's the case that should be counter-intuitive to you.  It would be like flipping 2 coins and saying P(HH) = 1/3 because HT and TH are the same thing.  Counter-intuitive as it is, that's how photons really do behave.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find it easier to treat each person as a unique (distinct) thing.  Thus the total number of ways for 7 people to exit a total of 10 floors is 10^7 (each person can pick one of the 10 floors).  Next, the number of ways that these 7 people can exit on different floors is 10!/3! (the first person picks one of 10 floors, the next picks from the remaining 9 and so on).  Thus the probability (assuming all outcomes are equally likely) is (10!/3!)/10^7 which comes to 0.06048 or 6.048%.

Comment: Nobody waits for an elevator on the 1st floor so they can exit on the 1st floor, so there are really only $9$ choices.  $9!/(9-7)!/9^7$.

Comment: @BruceZ The task has unclear text, but I assume the people are waiting at the ground floor, not the 1st, so we should use 10 choices.

Comment: $\frac{A_{10}^{7}}{10^7}$